# .htaccess from one url to another internally

Tags: apache, http, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

What I am trying to accomplish is if the user writes in for example:
    http://domain.co.uk/projects/category1
or
    http://domain.co.uk/projects/category2
or
    category3 etc.

they will be redirected to

```
http://domain.co.uk/projects/
```

I have no real experience with htaccess so any help here would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^projects/([^/]+)$    http://domain.co.uk/projects/   [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Worth noting for those who don't grok regexes and mod_rewrite that this matches all URLs beginning projects/ followed by anything other than a / and issues an HTTP 301 (Permanent Redirect) to http://domain.co.uk/projects/